# JavaScript changing prototype property value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function Fruit() {
    this.type = "fruit";
}

function Bannana() {
    this.color = "yellow";
    Fruit.call( this );
}

// instantiation
var myBanana = new Bannana();

// modifying type property    
Bannana.prototype.type = 'flower';

console.log( myBanana.type );
```

Output: `fruit` why is it not `flower`?

Comment: Somehow you keep having wrong expectations :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `myBanana` has its **own** `type` property which **shadows** the one on the prototype.

[image]

When you are accessing a property, it is first looked up on the object itself. Only if it doesn't exist, it is looked up on its prototype, the prototype's prototype, etc until it is found.

If it is not found, `undefined` will be returned.

Comment: Ok. What if I want to change the `type` to `flower`. How can I do this?

Comment: Just like you do with any other property `myBanana.type = 'flower';` If you want that every `Banana` instance **shares** the same `type` property (instead of having their own) then you have to set it on the prototype, not in the constructor. I.e. remove `this.type = '...';` and add `Fruit.prototype.type = '...';` or `Banana.prototype.type = '...';`.

Comment: Ok thanks! Explanation is clear. Is there an MDN article I can read up on with regards to looking up stuff and working up the prototype chain?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Answer (score 1):

`Fruit.call(this);` invokes `Fruit` with the new `Bannana` object as the *this* context, thus settings those properties directly on the object.

You can see this behaviour clearly by invoking the same pattern on an object literal.

```
var banana = {};

Fruit.call(banana);

console.log(banana.type); // 'fruit'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the call to `Fruit.call( this );` in the *Bannana* constructor set the object property *type* to *fruit* (i.e. it was set in the object *myBanana* in your code).

It would only fall back to a property in the prototype if the property *type* were not present in the object *myBanana*.

Try appending the following to your code and you'll see that `flower` will be the output:

```
delete myBanana.type
console.log(myBanana.type);
```

This happens because the *myBanana* object won't have the *type* property itself anymore, so the look up for the *type* property will walk up the prototype chain.

Check this answer to see how this mechanism works in more detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/572996/689788